# Difference Between k-center and k-mean/median

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, approximation, search-problem

I know that k-mean/median is to find a set $F$ that minimize
$$\sum_{i\in C}\min_{j \in F} d(i,j)$$
Where $C$ is set of clients and $F$ set of facilities. (For k-mean you just square the distance).

The thing I am confused about is what is k-center about? Is it similar to k-mean/median?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing research on this subject for quite some time. I faced a lot of confusion in the beginning, but now it is clear. The following is an answer close to completion:

The $k$-median problem is defined as follows: Given a set $C$ of clients and a set $L$ of facility locations defined over a distance metric $d$. Open a set $F$ of $k$ facility such that $F \subseteq L$ and the total cost of assigning the clients to their closest facilities is minimized, i.e.,

$$\text{minimize} \quad \Phi_C(F) \equiv \sum_{i \in C} \, \min_{j \in F} \big\{ d(j,i) \big\}$$

If the distance $d(.,.)$ is replaced with $d(.,.)^{2}$, it is known as the $k$-means problem (referenced from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.11850.pdf)).

---

In the [$k$-center problem](http://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edragan/ST/papers/p-centerHoShm.pdf), there are two changes:

1. $C = L$
2. The objective function is to find $F\subseteq L$ of size $k$ that minimize $\max_{i \in C} \Big\{ \min_{j \in F} d(i,j) \Big\}$. That is, we aim to minimize the maximum distance from a client to the closest facility.

Now, when $C$ is not necessarily the same as $L$, the $k$-center problem is known as the [$k$-supplier problem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36694-9_25).

---

However, for the $k$-median and $k$-means problem, when $C= L$, there is no different name given for the problem. However, in very few pieces of literature, they call the $k$-means problem with $L = C$ as the [$k$-medoid problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids).

---

**Summary:** You should differentiate the $k$-median/$k$-means/$k$-center problems on the basis of the *objective function* only. The remaining details like if $C = L$ or not, must be taken from where you are reading it from. Different authors make different assumptions. Furthermore, these assumptions can be of the following form:

Type of Space:

1. The space can be Euclidean, i.e., $d(.,.)$ is $\ell_{2}$ norm or Euclidean norm
2. The space can be $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, with distance measure $d(.,.)$ as $\ell_{1}$ norm, i.e., taxi-cab norm. **Be careful here:** In the solution to this problem, the optimal center of a cluster is the co-ordinate median of the points in the cluster. Therefore, some people like to call this problem, [the $k$-median problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering).
3. Likewise, space can be $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, but with distance functions: $\ell_{0},\dotsc, \ell_{\infty}$ (see [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02360762/document) and related references for the studies done on this topic).
4. The space can be non-metric also, where distances do not follow the properties of metric space, like symmetry, triangle inequality, etc. (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0205047.pdf) and related references for the studies done on this topic)

Continuous or Discontinuous Space:

1. In the $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ space, it possible that $L$ is given to you as a discrete/finte set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. More precisely, we call this problem as the discrete $k$-median/$k$-means/$k$-center problem.
2. On the other hand, it is possible that the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is the feasible set of facility locations, i.e., $L = \mathbb{R}^{d}$. We call this the continuous space. It means that there are infinitely many facility locations and also $C \subseteq L$. Therefore, an algorithm for discrete $k$-median/$k$-means/$k$-center will not work here. (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.00087.pdf) and related references for the studies done on this topic)

---

Please let me know in the comments if you want me to add something more, in case I missed something.

Comment: I am doubting whether this is accurate.  The statement of the $k$-means and $k$-medians problem that I am familiar with does not contain any requirement that $F \subseteq L$; it allows $F$ to be arbitrary.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @D.W. arbitrary means what precisely?

Comment: It means that $F$ can be any subset of  $\mathbb{R}^d$ (well, it has to have contain $k$ points).  In particular, there is no input $L$ to the algorithm.

Comment: @D.W. Yes that version is known as the **continuous** **Euclidean** $k$-median/$k$-means problem (if using $\ell_{2}$-norm as distance measure). The first definition is the most general definition. It encapsulates the definition that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the k-center problem, $F$ must be a subset of $C$; that is, you can only build facilities on top of clients.

In the k-mean/median problem, this is not required: you can build facilities anywhere in the metric space.